# Trouble with joining two lists together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists. And I want to join them like this:

```
[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3] => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[1], [2, 3] => [1, 2]
[], [1, 2, 3] => []
[4, 5, 6, 7], [1] => [4, 1]
```

Is there simple way to do it without `itertools?` It seems that I figured out how to do it :

```
new_list = first_list+second_list
new_list[::2] = first_list
new_list[1::2] = second_list
return new_list
```

But it only works with the lists of same length

Comment: use `zip` it's exactly done for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `zip` with your list of lists (you can have as many sub-lists as you want) passed as arguments using `*` unpacking and flatten the items (`zip` stops at the shortest list):

```
s = [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]

result = [y for x in zip(*s) for y in x]
```

which amounts to (for those not used to parameter unpacking):

```
first_list = [1, 2, 3]
second_list = [1, 2, 3]
result = [y for x in zip(first_list,second_list) for y in x]
```

result:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

with `s = [1], [2, 3]` you get `[1,2]` as expected

Comment: Could you explain please, what this * operator means?

Comment: it is unpacking for lists and pass as arguments.

Comment: I would suggest to keep the same format of input and output he suggested, `first_list`, `second_list` and `new_list` as that helps to make the code easier to understand for newbies.

Comment: @Adirio thanks for the edit (I rejected it but updated my answer to provide both approaches, cos you're right)

Comment: No problem, your answer is still yours

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for row in zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]) for x in row]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
>>> [x for row in zip([1], [2, 3]) for x in row]
[1, 2]
>>> [x for row in zip([], [1, 2, 3]) for x in row]
[]
>>> [x for row in zip([4, 5, 6, 7], [1]) for x in row]
[4, 1]
```

If you want to get every element from the longest list, you could use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [x for row in zip_longest([4, 5, 6, 7], [1]) for x in row]
[4, 1, 5, None, 6, None, 7, None]
```

It adds `None` elements to the shortest list.

Answer (score 2):

This function works for these cases mentioned and beyond!

```
def joo(l1,l2):
    l = []
    for i in range(min(len(l1), len(l2))):
        l.append(l1[i])
        l.append(l2[i])
    return l
l = joo(l1, l2)
```

Thanks to Adirio for suggestions!

Comment: I suggested some changes that improve your script by not using globals and removing a `if` that was not needed if you first calculate the min.

Comment: @Adirio thanks! it should be min of len of l1 and l2 right

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip:

```
def zip_lists(list1, list2):
    return [a for b in zip(list1, list2) for a in b]

print(zip_lists([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]))  # => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
print(zip_lists([1], [2, 3]))  # => [1, 2]
print(zip_lists([], [1, 2, 3]))  # => []
print(zip_lists([4, 5, 6, 7], [1]))  # => [4, 1]
```

Comment: And you could read the previous answers ;) BTW, there's no need to convert an iterable (zip) to a list if you want to iterate one it.